# Cannot call method 'transaction' of null

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage, web-sql

I'm getting the following error

Cannot call method 'transaction' of null

when trying to insert into WEBSQL (yes, i'm aware its deprecated).

i have an almost exact duplicate of this script working fine on another page, this one just has a different name and separate fields.  code is below.

```
var html5rocks = {};
html5rocks.webdb = {};

html5rocks.webdb.db = null;

html5rocks.webdb.open = function() {
    var dbSize = 5 * 1024 * 1024; // 5MB
    html5rocks.webdb.db = openDatabase('Customer', '1.0', 'customer manager', dbSize);
}

html5rocks.webdb.onError = function(tx, e) {
    alert('Something unexpected happened: ' + e.message );
    console.log('error');
}

html5rocks.webdb.onSuccess = function(tx, r) {


    var statusOutput = "Customer Form Saved!";
    var status = document.getElementById('status');
    $('.form-title-area').css('background-color','#26c622');
    $('.form-title-area').html('<h1>Customer Form Saved!</h1>');
    status.innerHTML = statusOutput;

    html5rocks.webdb.getAllTodoItems(loadTodoItems);
}

html5rocks.webdb.createTable = function() {
    html5rocks.webdb.db.transaction(function(tx) {
                                    tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ' + 
                                                  'customerform(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ASC, companyname TEXT, tradingas TEXT, regadd1 TEXT, regadd2 TEXT, regaddcity TEXT, regaddstate TEXT, regaddcountry TEXT, regaddpostcode TEXT, cregno TEXT, vatregno TEXT, accountsname TEXT,  accountsphone TEXT, accountsemail TEXT, accountsfax TEXT, invadd1 TEXT, invadd2 TEXT, invaddcity TEXT, invaddstate TEXT, invaddcountry TEXT, invaddpostcode TEXT, creditlimit TEXT, firstorder TEXT, reqdeldate TEXT, deladd1 TEXT, deladd2 TEXT, deladdcity TEXT, deladdstate TEXT, deladdcountry TEXT, deladdpostcode TEXT, buyingname TEXT, buyingphone TEXT, buyingemail TEXT, buyingfax TEXT, ordersource TEXT, currency TEXT, deliveryterms TEXT, maxpallet TEXT, pallettype TEXT, wrap TEXT, invoiceterms TEXT, specialinstructions TEXT, bookingname TEXT, bookingphone TEXT, signed TEXT, signeddate TEXT, inputby TEXT, inputdate TEXT, added_on DATETIME)', []);
                                    });


}

html5rocks.webdb.addTodo = function(companynameText, tradingasText, regadd1Text, regadd2Text, regaddcityText, regaddstateText, regaddcountryText, regaddpostcodeText, cregnoText, vatregnoText, accountsnameText, accountsphoneText, accountsemailText, accountsfaxText, invadd1Text, invadd2Text, invaddcityText, invaddstateText, invaddcountryText, invaddpostcodeText, creditlimitText, firstorderText, reqdeldateText, deladd1Text, deladd2Text, deladdcityText, deladdstateText, deladdcountryText, deladdpostcodeText, buyingnameText, buyingphoneText, buyingemailText, buyingfaxText, ordersourceText, currencyText, deliverytermsText, maxpalletText, wrapText, invoicetermsText, specialinstructionsText, bookingnameText, bookingphoneText, signedText, signeddateText, inputbyText, inputdatetext) {


    html5rocks.webdb.db.transaction(function(tx){


                                    var addedOn = new Date();
                                    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO customerform(companyname, tradingas, regadd1, regadd2, regaddcity, regaddstate, regaddcountry, regaddpostcode, cregno, vatregno, accountsname, accountsphone , accountsemail, accountsfax, invadd1, invadd2, invaddcity, invaddstate, invaddcountry, invaddpostcode, creditlimit, firstorder, reqdeldate, deladd1, deladd2, deladdcity, deladdstate, deladdcountry, deladdpostcode, buyingname, buyingphone ,buyingemail, buyingfax, ordersource, currency, deliveryterms, maxpallet, pallettype, wrap, invoiceterms, specialinstructions, bookingname, bookingphone, signed, signeddate, inputby, inputdate, added_on) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)', 
                                                  [companynameText, tradingasText, regadd1Text, regadd2Text, regaddcityText, regaddstateText, regaddcountryText, regaddpostcodeText, cregnoText, vatregnoText, accountsnameText, accountsphoneText, accountsemailText, accountsfaxText, invadd1Text, invadd2Text, invaddcityText, invaddstateText, invaddcountryText, invaddpostcodeText, creditlimitText, firstorderText, reqdeldateText, deladd1Text, deladd2Text, deladdcityText, deladdstateText, deladdcountryText, deladdpostcodeText, buyingnameText, buyingphoneText, buyingemailText, buyingfaxText, ordersourceText, currencyText, deliverytermsText, maxpalletText, pallettypeText, wrapText, invoicetermsText, specialinstructionsText, bookingnameText, bookingphoneText, signedText, signeddateText, inputbyText, inputdateText, addedOn],
                                                  html5rocks.webdb.onSuccess,
                                                  html5rocks.webdb.onError);
                                    });


}




function init() {
    html5rocks.webdb.open();
    html5rocks.webdb.createTable();
    html5rocks.webdb.getAllTodoItems(loadTodoItems);

}

function initi() {

    html5rocks.webdb.getRecords();
}

function addTodo() {
console.log('trigger');
    var companyname = document.getElementById('companyname');
    var tradingas = document.getElementById('tradingas');
    var regadd1 = document.getElementById('regadd1');
    var regadd2 = document.getElementById('regadd2');
    var regaddcity = document.getElementById('regaddcity');
    var regaddstate = document.getElementById('regaddstate');
    var regaddcountry = document.getElementById('regaddcountry');
    var regaddpostcode = document.getElementById('regaddpostcode');
    var cregno = document.getElementById('cregno');
    var vatregno = document.getElementById('vatregno');
    //var vatregno = $('vatregno').val();
    var accountsname = document.getElementById('accountsname');
    var accountsphone = document.getElementById('accountsphone');
    var accountsemail = document.getElementById('accountsemail');
    var accountsfax = document.getElementById('accountsfax');
    var invadd1 = document.getElementById('invadd1');
    var invadd2 = document.getElementById('invadd2');
    var invaddcity = document.getElementById('invaddcity');
    var invaddstate = document.getElementById('invaddstate');
    var invaddcountry = document.getElementById('invaddcountry');
    var invaddpostcode = document.getElementById('invaddpostcode');
    var creditlimit = document.getElementById('creditlimit');
    var firstorder = document.getElementById('firstorder');
    var reqdeldate = $('.reqdeldate');
    var deladd1 = document.getElementById('deladd1');
    var deladd2 = document.getElementById('deladd2');
    var deladdcity = document.getElementById('deladdcity');
    var deladdstate = document.getElementById('deladdstate');
    var deladdcountry = document.getElementById('deladdcountry');
    var deladdpostcode = document.getElementById('deladdpostcode');
    var buyingname = document.getElementById('buyingname');
    var buyingphone = document.getElementById('buyingphone');
    var buyingemail = document.getElementById('buyingemail');
    var buyingfax = document.getElementById('buyingfax');
    var ordersource = document.getElementById('ordersource');
    var currency = document.getElementById('currency');
    var deliveryterms = document.getElementById('deliveryterms');
    var maxpallet = document.getElementById('maxpallet');
    var pallettype = document.getElementById('pallettype');
    var wrap = document.getElementById('wrap');
    var invoiceterms = document.getElementById('invoiceterms');
    var specialinstructions = document.getElementById('specialinstructions');
    var bookingname = document.getElementById('bookingname');
    var bookingphone = document.getElementById('bookingphone');
    var signed = document.getElementById('signed');
    var signeddate = $('.signeddate');
    var inputby = document.getElementById('inputby');

    var inputdate = $('.inputdate');

    console.log('triggers2');



    html5rocks.webdb.addTodo(companyname.value, tradingas.value, regadd1.value, regadd2.value, regaddcity.value, regaddstate.value, regaddcountry.value, regaddpostcode.value, cregno.value, vatregno.value, accountsname.value, accountsphone.value, accountsemail.value, accountsfax.value, invadd1.value, invadd2.value, invaddcity.value, invaddstate.value, invaddcountry.value, invaddpostcode.value, creditlimit.value, firstorder.value, reqdeldate.value, deladd1.value, deladd2.value, deladdcity.value, deladdstate.value, deladdcountry.value, deladdpostcode.value, buyingname.value, buyingphone.value, buyingemail.value, buyingfax.value, ordersource.value, currency.value, deliveryterms.value, maxpallet.value, pallettype.value, wrap.value, invoiceterms.value, specialinstructions.value, bookingname.value, bookingphone.value, signed.value, signeddate.value, inputby.value, inputdate.value);

    alert('Customer Form Saved');

}
```

does anyone have any ideas what the issue actually is? i'm stumped

Comment: Does the `openDatabase()` function return an object with `transaction`, and is the `openDatabase()` function asynchronous, as the problem probably is that the `transaction` object, which has some sort of callback, does not exist at the time you are trying to call it.

Comment: @adeneo that comment is a bit beyond me, is there somewhere i can throw a console.log to check that info?

Comment: Not sure what is wrong with your code. Maybe you can create a http://jsfiddle.net/ to show it in action. But just one moment: you are doing `var signeddate = $('.signeddate');` and than take `signeddate.value`. That will always return undefined. You should do `signeddate.val()` as you are working with jQuery object here, not pure DOM object. And few other elements with same issue.

Comment: @FAngel thanks for the info, they were next in the queue after i solved this transaction issue. have updated them since and it doesn't effect the above error unfortunately

Comment: Are you sure you are calling `init` before method which calls a transaction?

Comment: @FAngel I am triggering the whole script with init from the onsubmit action of the form.

Comment: Any other errors in console? Maybe something happens before webdb.open() is executed and it stays not opened actually. Right now I see nothing except that webdb.open is not executed.

Comment: none at all, just Viewport target-densitydpi is not supported. but that's due to it being built for phonegap not the browser.

Comment: And on which row exactly it throws an error? As for now, I do not see any problem except that `html5rocks.webdb.open();` is not executed or executed after method which throws an error. I've tried to reproduce an issue, but see no problem. But your code does not show whole picture.

Comment: Think i have it sorted, i've built a barebones version based on my other working page and it seems to work, I'll just have to re-add all the fields the long way.